# Finding primes $p$ such that $x\equiv y $ mod $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given values of $x$ and $y$ can we find prime $p$ such that $x\equiv y \mod p$ holds?
In other words, how to find the least value of $p$ which divides $\mid x-y\mid$.
Is it possible to find value of $p$ using some formula or we need to try every possible values of $p$?

Example: for $x=87$ and $y=12$, $\ p=3$.

Answer (score 2):

You can factor $|x-y|$ and take the smallest prime.

Comment: yeah that is right but can it be done mathematically through formula besides prime factorization because what if |x-y| is big prime itself?

Comment: I don't know of any way.  Factoring composites is thought to be hard.  This would be a way to do it.

Comment: thank you @RossMillikan for answering, though i am looking for a better or clever way besides factorization:)

Comment: @bhavik Any general algorithm for finding the least (prime) factor yields an algorithm for factorization, and conversely. So your problem is equivalent to integer factorization.